# In a linked list, why don't we give a name to each node?

Tags: linked-list

I see people usually use a temp node to manipulate a linked list. For example, create a new node whose pointer is stored in temp, point previous block to temp, then use temp for the next node.

Why not keep a designated name to each node(keep a variable that stores its address), so that we can access that node by simply dereferencing its name. This way, we can still insert a new node by pointing the previous node to it and pointing it to the next node.

I know there is a reason why linked list is not made this way, I just can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked list data type is simply not made for having a name for each item. In many cases you simply just don't need to name everything. If you need such behavior you can extend the type for your needs.

It all comes down to: Use the data structure which fits to your actual use case.

In Java for example there is a pre-defined type which does exactly, what you have described:
[`LinkedHashMap<K, V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)